# SQL Server stored procedure with or without output parameter

Tags: sql-server

I'm still learning SQL and can't understand the difference between these 2 as below:

Approach #1:

```
create proc sp_test1
    @count int out,
    @SalePrice int
as
begin 
   SELECT @Count = COUNT(*) 
   FROM dbo.SalesHistory 
   WHERE SalePrice = @SalePrice;
end

declare @Count int;

exec sp_test1 @SalePrice = '967', @Count = @Count output;

select @Count;
```

Approach #2:

```
create proc sp_test2
    @SalePrice int
as
begin 
    SELECT COUNT(*) 
    FROM dbo.SalesHistory 
    WHERE SalePrice = @SalePrice;
end

exec sp_test2 @SalePrice = '967';
```

Both should return a number. But what's the difference between these two? In what scenario do I use each? Thank you guys!

Comment: Side note: you should **not** use the `sp_` prefix for your stored procedures. Microsoft has [reserved that prefix for its own use (see *Naming Stored Procedures*)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190669%28v=sql.105%29.aspx), and you do run the risk of a name clash sometime in the future. [It's also bad for your stored procedure performance](http://www.sqlperformance.com/2012/10/t-sql-queries/sp_prefix). It's best to just simply avoid `sp_` and use something else as a prefix - or no prefix at all!

Comment: @marc_s sorry, I should've put schema name before "sp_test1". Thank you for the reminder.

Answer (score 1):

In this scenario there is no practical difference and no real reason to do the extra work to create the output parameter.

An example of where an output parameter would be useful is a situation where a dataset is coming back from the stored procedure, but you also want a single piece of information that applies to the whole set .... for instance maybe you want the exact time that SQL Server executed the query.  Or maybe there are a number of such items.  You could return those as separate "SELECT ..." datasets, but that can be messy and not be as clear in application code what is being returned. Rather than having named output parameters you would only have indexed tables. Thus, that would be a sensible spot to consider using output parameters.

Output parameters are never required, but they can be a nice option to return scalar data to the calling application.

Answer (score 0):

Both procedures are similar but application may be different for example lets assume that you are creating a web page and there is a grid. when we are placing a grid typically we are  paging the data set, and end user needs to know how many pagers in there. in such cases you can use the second implementation.

fist implementation is very much straight forward you are just selecting a data set from the data base.

lastly i would like to highlight Output parameters are optional.

Comment: Did you mean the second one is straight forward?

Comment: I'm sorry its not the second one its the first statement